# Calculate the video progress bar percentage

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, progress-bar

Am developing chapters on the video. Based on the provided time (for example)

00:00 - Welcome

01:20 - Introduction

03:20 - The end

I have the html as like below:

```
<div class="overall-chapter-layer">
<div class="time-layer" width="0%">
<div class="progress-layer"></div>
</div>
```

Since 3 chapters provided. Now, the progress bars will be rendered based on the given time. In UI level, it will look like three Progress bars. (Just as like Youtube chapters)

Here, While video is playing need to update the progress. Since 3 chapters are provided, need to update the progress bar for each from 0 to 100%.

For the first progress bar am calculating the progress bar percentage as like below:

```
current_video_time / current_vid_duration * 100
```

Am missing the logic to calculate the progress bar percentage for remaining chapters. am trying like

```
(current_video_time - current_vid_duration[i-1])/(current_vid_duration[i] - current_vid_duration[i-1]) )*100;
```

Comment: **(1)** What is the end time (duration) of the video? You need a range for the third chapter until video's end time. **(2)** Why is 1 progress bar not enough? Are you expecting to show how far each chapter was played (hence each chapter has it's own progress bar)? If yes, then that's gonna be complicated. You need to ratio the chapter's **start** and **end** as **0 to 1** range. Basically `1 / numSecs_In_This_Chapter`. Then multiply the full-size width of chapter's progress bar by the ratio.

Comment: PS: You'll need other checks like if I skip chapter 1 halfway then progress bar of chapter1 is at 0.5, I now play 10 seconds of chapter 3, then seek back to chapter 1 and it gets complicated here because **(1)** You have to disregard the seconds I've already watched (if I seek too far back, less than 0.5). **(2)** If instead I seek back to 0.8 (not the previous stop point of 0.5) then you have to add these new seconds to the chapter's watch progress. Does your progress bar say 100% if I watch from 0.8 to full 1.0? Does it disregard that I skipped from between 0.5 up to 0.8?

Comment: PPS: You say _"...Just as like Youtube chapters"_ but Youtube is not creating multiple progress bars. There is only 1 timeline and 1 progress bar. Everything (separate blocks) is just visual presentation. You could use masks (are thin on mouse rollout, and thick on mouse rollover) or SVG shapes (with gap in middle) to show the grey progress bar which on a layer underneath... Decide if you want 3 progress bars or you want a similar result to Youtube's chapters UI design.